# Configure Sencha Touch icons for Ext.Msg.alert and Ext.Msg.confirm?

Tags: sencha-touch

How can I specify a custom icon for these Sencha Touch events:

- `Ext.Msg.alert`
- `Ext.Msg.confirm`

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @douga, I resolved to specify a custom icon on Ext.Msg.confirm with CSS class and tags into my Sencha code. .customIcon {background-image:url();background-position: x y;}.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

On the Ext.Msg (MessageBox) you can specify and `iconCls` config item to control the icon used.

The icons should be 40x40 and you'd obviously want to reference css class which has a `background: url();` pointing to you icons url.

Since alert and confirm are subsets of messagebox, the config item should be available on them aswell.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently created this new app that will help you to prepare named icons that you can assign to `iconCls`. It generates the SCCS file for your Sencha Touch apps. The README explains the steps for creating icons at the Ico Moon web site and using the tool to convert Ico Moon project files into SCSS for use in Sencha Touch.  This has also been tested with Sencha Architect projects.

- https://github.com/tohagan/sencha-ico-moon